# Printing a collection of articles in a 'proceedings' for a maths conference

Tags: publications, conference

I am organising a one day meeting on a maths topic. I would like to print a proceedings consisting  of papers recommended by each of the (seven) speakers to try and keep a review of the topics discussed. No profit will be made, all copies will be provided free.

Is this possible? Is this unprofessional? What copyright laws would I encounter from journals (where a paper may have already appeared)? Can I collect papers without calling it a publication?

Answer (score 1):

This [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proceedings) may assit you. However I believe that as long as you have permissions from the authors/journals there should not be a problem. Also I take it you have sourced these papers legally etc?

Comment: Yes, each participant will hopefully recommend a paper (i.e. the one their talk is based on). I would then seek permission if it has already appeared.

Comment: Then as far as I am aware, if you are dealing with the author's directly then you should have no issue, jsut so long as you state that the papers were reccomended by them and that they are t be used for the proceedings only. It is a case of being as open as possible.